# Firebase Role based authorization

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, firebase-security

I have 3 users which is for admin, manager and user. How can i create a role based function in firebase? Where admin can view, write certain page, manager can read, write, edit, while user can only read? on my database firebase (realtime) i changed to this rules:-

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm stuck with this. i managed to create an account but its not restrict to pages. how can i change it? Please help me

Answer (score 1):

See [Control Access with Custom Claims and Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims)

> The Firebase Admin SDK supports defining custom attributes on user
>   accounts. This provides the ability to implement various access
>   control strategies, including role-based access control, in Firebase
>   apps. These custom attributes can give users different levels of
>   access (roles), which are enforced in an application's security rules.
>
> ```
> {
>   "rules": {
>     "adminContent": {
>       ".read": "auth.token.admin === true",
>       ".write": "auth.token.admin === true",
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```